# Status change of Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, servicebus

I have created a SB in the azure portal. By default the status is showing as Active. Let me have a scenario where i want to change the status of this SB, any idea on how to do that? Any pointers will be very helpful. We have 2 service bus and one needs to be active at a time. So how can we manage that?

Comment: once you provision an azure servicebus you can go ahead and start using the queues, topics, subscriptions, relay etc. I am not sure what exactly are you referring to as status.

Comment: Are you referring to "namespaces"? You can't enable or disable a namespace. You can only do that to entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default the status is showing as Active. Let me have a scenario where i want to change the status of this SB, any idea on how to do that?

Service Bus works as a container or a namespace. The status of Azure Service Bus is internal used, we can't change it on Azure portal or using any API.

As @Sean Feldman said, we can only enable or disable the entities(queues or  topics) in the Service Bus in the properties panel.

[image]

To disable all the queues and topics in a Service Bus, you could using following code.

```
string connectionString = "your connection string of service bus";
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

IEnumerable<QueueDescription> queueList = namespaceManager.GetQueues();

foreach (QueueDescription qd in queueList)
{
    qd.Status = EntityStatus.Disabled;
    namespaceManager.UpdateQueue(qd);
}

IEnumerable<TopicDescription> topicList = namespaceManager.GetTopics();

foreach (TopicDescription td in topicList)
{
    td.Status = EntityStatus.Disabled;
    namespaceManager.UpdateTopic(td);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just want to know whether we can change the status or not. Any idea why the status of the service bus cannot be changed. There can be some valid scenarios in the real world problems where a active and passive SB can be used.